# MySQL get average values per hour from the last 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following query to get the average values per hour for one day, but I don't get it to result the latest data instead of the oldest:

```
SELECT id, serverID, AVG(performance) as performance, AVG(online) as online, HOUR(timestamp)
    FROM stats_server
    WHERE serverID= :serverID AND DATE_SUB(`timestamp`,INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
    ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Are you talking about the order?  If so why not try `ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: nope, this query already limits the output by 24 results, so order works fine but only for the 24 results

Comment: You're missing something in the "DATE_SUB" part of the WHERE clause: something like `timestamp > DATE_SUB(timestamp, INTERVAL 24 HOUR)`. Besides, you're asking for 1 hour, while you want 24 (so to group by them)

Comment: You missied condition for DATE_SUB:  `AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(`timestamp`,INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

Comment: @Uriil if I add this, the result is the same.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, **"but I don't get it to result the latest data instead of the oldest"**?

Comment: Could you setup SQL fiddle, and provide Input and expected output?

Comment: @Linger e.g. table with records of 2 weeks, I run this query I get the results from the first day and not the latest.

Comment: @Uriil sql fiddle is down :( http://i.imgur.com/cJim9d5.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mention the last 24 hours data:

```
SELECT id, serverID, AVG(performance) as performance, AVG(online) as online, 
HOUR(timestamp) FROM stats_server
WHERE serverID= :serverID AND DATE_SUB(`timestamp`,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) And 
timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: thats another way to solve it, I haven't thought about, thanks.

Comment: sorry, I just noticed it doesn't work, as it shows the stats from "yesterday" and not the last 24 hours. Can we do the same with 24 hours?

Comment: Yes its correct NOW will take the time current stamp, thanks for updating me, i have edited